# How do I load symbols for F# libraries?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, f#, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

**How do I load symbols for F# libraries?**

I have a **Xamarin.Forms** app that relies on F# libraries. Unfortunately, I am unable to step through my F# code because I believe the symbols for those libraries never get loaded.

**Note:**
I was not able to reference F# projects within my Xamarin.Forms and Droid projects. As a result, I added references to F# DLLs via bin folder file paths.

I have attempted to point to the bin\debug folder to load the symbols that reflect my F# libraries.[image]

I also displayed the Modules window. Yet, I didn't observe any modules get loaded.

[image]

In conclusion, I am not sure what actions I need to take so that I can step through the debugger for my F# code.

**I then observed the following exception:**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/FnTrade.Droid/files/.**override**/en-US/FSharp.Core.resources.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies

Comment: Something is not right here, if you are attached to the process you should see modules.

Comment: Okay. I'm debugging on my local machine. I didn't know I had to attach to anything. I thought I just had to point to a DLL folder.

Comment: How are you debugging? How did you start the debugging session?

Comment: I launched my Droid emulator from my Xamarin.Forms app. The Droid project is set as the startup project.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4819cfc2-b438-4e58-a519-c134f75c4a99/compilation-error-with-f-30-in-a-multiproject-solution?forum=fsharpgeneral

Comment: Under the symbols option, we could load the symbols(.pdb) manually, but one issue is that how you really refer to the dll or executable file if you couldn't refer to it in the solution explorer window? How about using attach to process like this sample? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271945/is-there-a-way-in-visual-studio-2012-to-use-f-repl-when-debugging-c-sharp

Comment: Does the code run when you are not debugging?

Comment: Yes. The app loads data generated from my F# libraries.